# How to generate client code using with swagger-codegen-plugin (maven)?

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

I need to generate a server stub code in  eclipse using with swagger-codegen-plugin (for maven) . can you please help how to do it ? and what configuration needed for that( in pom.xml).

Comment: The title says generate client code, the body says server code, which do you really want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this answer. You just need to change pom.xml like below.

pom.xml.

```
<properties>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
           <version.swagger.codegen>2.2.1</version.swagger.codegen>
           <yaml.file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Api.yaml</yaml.file>
           <generated-sources-path>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generated-sources-path>
           <generated-sources-java-path>main/java</generated-sources-java-path>
       </properties>

<build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                   <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${version.swagger.codegen}</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <inputSpec>${yaml.file}</inputSpec>
                       <configOptions>
                           <sourceFolder>${generated-sources-java-path}</sourceFolder>
                       </configOptions>
                       <output>${generated-sources-path}</output>
                   </configuration>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>generate-swagger-spring</id>
                           <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>generate</goal>
                           </goals>
                           <configuration>
                               <language>spring</language>
                               <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.swagger.model</modelPackage>
                               <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.swagger.api</apiPackage>
                               <invokerPackage>${project.groupId}.swagger.invoker</invokerPackage>
                           </configuration>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>        
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>add-generated-source</id>
                           <phase>initialize</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>add-source</goal>
                           </goals>
                           <configuration>
                               <sources>
                                   <source>${generated-sources-path}/${generated-sources-java-path}</source>
                               </sources>
                           </configuration>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>                
           </plugins>   

       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                   <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                   <version>1.0.0</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                           <pluginExecutions>
                               <pluginExecution>
                                   <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                       <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                                       <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                       <versionRange>[${version.swagger.codegen},)</versionRange>
                                       <goals>
                                           <goal>generate</goal>
                                       </goals>
                                   </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                   <action>
                                       <execute />
                                   </action>
                               </pluginExecution>
                           </pluginExecutions>
                       </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>          
       </build>
```

Comment: Note that the plugin management part is eclipse specific. You should only need it for Eclipse support (i.e. plain maven should not need it). But for eclipse this is important and hard to find when just googling for the error it prints when this is not there.

Comment: It seems <language>spring</language> will generate server side code and <language>java</language> will generate client side code. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5332

Comment: You can also use json file instead of yml. Just manually convert yml to json first.

Answer (score 5):

```
<!-- Swagger -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>contract-service</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/rest-data-exchange-format.yaml</inputSpec>
                <artifactId>contract-service</artifactId>
                <output>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</output>
                <language>spring</language>
                <modelPackage>ru.payhub.rest.v1.model</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>ru.payhub.rest.v1.api</apiPackage>
                <!-- <invokerPackage>ru.payhub.rest.v1.handler</invokerPackage> -->
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <library>spring-boot</library>
                    <dateLibrary>${generator.datelibrary}</dateLibrary>
                    <configPackage>ru.payhub.config</configPackage>
                    <singleContentTypes>true</singleContentTypes>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Official parametrs description [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin)

Swagger syntax specification [here](https://swagger.io/specification/)

On this example maven plugin, used swagger data-model file (yaml) generate model classes for use it in the controllers.

Comment: Could you please tell where did you get those config options? They are not on the page linked.

Comment: @AleksandrErokhin, which options for your question? All available opts you can found in "Official parametrs description" and into ofiicial page or github project
(https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/README.md)

Comment: I was looking for the list of `configOptions` and there is none on the official page.

Answer (score 4):

Sample configuration for `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` is available at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

List of possible languages is available here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages